# How can I return a file using spring without changing the encoding, or just set up UTF-8-BOM encoding

Tags: spring, csv, encoding, utf-8, byte-order-mark

I have a method that reads data from a database, which stores data from a csv file in json format. This method creates a csv file from the received data.

```
String fileName = "res/testCreate.csv";

try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter (new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileName), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))) {
            String stringPipes = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT data from PIPES WHERE pipeName='" + pipeName + "' AND snapshotDate='" + snapshotDate + "'", String.class);
            JsonNode jsonTree = new ObjectMapper().readTree(stringPipes);
            CsvSchema.Builder builder = CsvSchema.builder();
            JsonNode firstObject = jsonTree.elements().next();

            firstObject.fieldNames().forEachRemaining(fieldName -> builder.addColumn(fieldName));

            CsvSchema csvSchema = builder.build();

            CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper();

            writer.write("\ufeff");
            csvMapper.writerFor(JsonNode.class)
                    .with(csvSchema.withColumnSeparator(';'))
                    .writeValue(writer, jsonTree);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "Error");
        }
```

In order for the file to be saved with UTF-8-BOM encoding, I write `writer.write("\ufeff");`.

But I cannot transfer the file with the encoding I need to the request, because the encoding changes to UTF-8.

I tried to do it in 3 ways.

1: Just return the CSV file using ResponseEntity

```
return ResponseEntity.ok()
                    .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName)
                    .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("text/csv; charset=UTF-8"))
                    .body(new FileSystemResource(new File(fileName)));
```

If I set the encoding to UTF-8, then the file will come with the encoding without BOM, if I install UTF-8-BOM, then an exeption appears that this encoding is not supported, if I do not set the encoding at all, then the default encoding is set, which is also not the one that is needed.

2: Return the CSV file using ResponseEntity<Resource>

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/getCSVFile")
    @ResponseBody
    @Operation(summary = "Получение Csv файла", tags = "Трубы. Редактирование")
    private ResponseEntity<Resource> getCSVFile() {
        Resource resource = new FileSystemResource(new File("res/testCreate.csv"));
        return ResponseEntity.ok().header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + resource.getFilename() + "\"").body(resource);
    }
```

The result is the same

3: I'm using HttpServletResponse, and I'm trying to write "\ufeff" just like I did in the method.

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/getCsvWithBOM")
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
    @Operation(summary = "Получение Csv файла с помощью Pojo", tags = "Трубы. Редактирование")
    public void getCsvWithBOM(
            @Parameter(description = SW.key) @RequestParam String pipeName,
            @Parameter(description = SW.key + "Строка в формате 'yyyy-DD-MM'", example = "2020-01-01") @RequestParam String snapshotDate,
            HttpServletResponse response
    ) {
        String fileName = "testCreate.csv";
        try {
            String stringPipes = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT data from PIPES WHERE pipeName='" + pipeName + "' AND snapshotDate='" + snapshotDate + "'", String.class);
            JsonNode jsonTree = new ObjectMapper().readTree(stringPipes);
            CsvSchema.Builder builder = CsvSchema.builder();
            JsonNode firstObject = jsonTree.elements().next();

            firstObject.fieldNames().forEachRemaining(fieldName -> builder.addColumn(fieldName));

            CsvSchema csvSchema = builder.build();

            CsvMapper csvMapper = new CsvMapper();
            response.setContentType("text/csv");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", String.format("attachment; filename=\"%s\"", fileName));

            response.getWriter().write('\ufeff');
            csvMapper.writerFor(JsonNode.class)
                    .with(csvSchema.withColumnSeparator(';'))
                    .writeValue(response.getWriter(), jsonTree);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

In this case, I am not creating a file, but generating one to send. But the file still comes with encoding UTF-8 and not with encoding UTF-8-BOM despite the fact that I wrote `response.getWriter().write('\ufeff');`.

Answer (score 0):

1. bw.write( 65279 ); // UTF-8의 BOM인 "EF BB BF"를 UTF-16BE 로 변환
2. s.substring( 1 );  // BOM REMOVE return.

sample
1.

```
>         BufferedWriter bw = null;
>         try
>         {
>             bw = new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter( new FileOutputStream( "out.txt" ) , "UTF-8" ) );
>             bw.write( 65279 ); // UTF-8의 BOM인 "EF BB BF"를 UTF-16BE 로 변환하면
>             bw.write( "ABC가나다라마바사아차카파타하" );
>             bw.newLine( );
>             bw.write( "ㄴㅇㄹㅇㄱ붹가나카깐ㄹ깕" );
>         }
>         catch ( UnsupportedEncodingException e )
>         {
>             e.printStackTrace( );
>         }
```

2. 

```
String lineSeparator = System.getProperty( "line.separator" );
Writer w = null;
BufferedReader r = null;
try
{
    boolean firstLine = true;
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream( "out.txt" );
    r = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( fis , "UTF-8" ) );
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream( "out_cp1252.txt" );
    //w = new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter( fos , "Cp1252" ) );
    w = new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter( fos , "MS949" ) );
    String s = null;
    for ( ; ( s = r.readLine( ) ) != null ; )
    {
        if ( firstLine )
        {
            if ( s.startsWith( UTF8_BOM ) )
            {
                s = s.substring( 1 );
            }
            firstLine = false;
        }
        w.write( s + lineSeparator );
        w.flush( );
    }
}
catch ( Exception e )
{
    e.printStackTrace( );
}
```